# MONGODB: Inconsistent query results (corrupted db?)

Tags: mongodb

Our app is running smoothly for about 2 years now (at least in the following aspect).
But some weeks ago some of our clients started complaining about a relevant count in the system. We investigated it, reduced the example to a minumum case, and ended up with this weird situation:

```
db.my_collection.find().count()
=> 250088

db.my_collection.distinct("field_1")
=> [false, true]

db.my_collection.find({"field_1":{$nin:[true, false]}}).count()
=> 0
db.my_collection.find({"field_1":{$in:[true, false]}}).count()
=> 250088


db.my_collection.find({"field_1":true}).count()
=> 140357
db.my_collection.find({"field_1":false}).count()
=> 109731
(140357 + 109731 = 250088, great!)


db.my_collection.find({"field_2":null}).count()
=> 4638
db.my_collection.find({"field_2":{$ne:null}}).count()
=> 245450
(4638 + 245450 = 250088, great!)


db.my_collection.find({"field_2":{$ne:null}, "field_1":{$in:[true, false]}}).count()
=> 245450 (great!)
```

But look at this:

```
db.my_collection.find({"field_2":null, "field_1":false}).count()
=> 2669
db.my_collection.find({"field_2":null, "field_1":true}).count()
=> 790
2669 + 790 = 3459 (should sum 4638 !!)

db.my_collection.find({"field_2":{$ne:null}, "field_1":false}).count()
=> 75795
db.my_collection.find({"field_2":{$ne:null}, "field_1":true}).count()
=> 107298
75795 + 107298 = 183093 (should sum 245450 !!)
```

Also1: This problem only happens with this specific fields composition in the query. If we compose each of these two fields with others, everything works fine (we didn't make an exaustive search here. But we tried a bunch of them)

Also2: We tried to make the queries with various diffeten hint values (including {$natural:1}), to see if it could be a corrupted index, but it is still broken.

Also3: We resync'd one of our seccondaries, and the error persists.

Also4: We coppied the collection, document by document, through the console and a find().forEach({insert}) query, (same db version) and IT WORKS CORRECTLY!!!

Also5: we're using mongodb 2.4.8.

WTF might be happening?
What should I do to correct it RIGHT?
What should I do to correct it FAST?

===== UPDATE 18-sep

We found out that we had some indexes with a key that was too large and mongodb 2.4 just logs and ignores it. So the index was silently breaking. (looks like mongo 2.6 solves this in a more polished way: http://docs.mongodb.org/master//release-notes/2.6-compatibility/#index-key-length-incompatibility )

We dropped those indexes (they were just some tests we made and forgot) and the queries came back home.

We just did not realize yet why we could not get right results when giving hints, even the $natural:1...

Comment: Can you post what indexes you have on this collection? I am thinking this could be an issue with sparse indexing, especially since you are dealing with nulls, and relatedly did you recreate the indexes on the copy of the collection when you tried it?

Comment: I updated the question. It was an index issue (not sparse), but we just missed it because we DID tested giving hints (even $natural:1) but it did not solve the issue... =(